# adding Event Listeners to the instance of a Custom Class

Tags: typescript

I have class for each of my page. So for Home, i have a home class and inside the home class are several HTMLElements. However, i want to dispatch an event from my home class that isn't tied to any particular HTMLElement so that my app.js can take action.

So for example:

```
export class app {
  private home: Home;

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.home = new Home();
    home.addEventListener(HomeEvent.TEST, this.myFunction); 
    //HomeEvent.TEST is just a static constant value "home-animation-event".
  }
}
```

again, this is probably trivial but I don't think I want to necessarily tie the eventlistener to a dom element or have app extend HTMLElement. What's the best approach for this please?

Comment: You can either fake one by using window.addEventListener and creating custom events to dispatch, or checkout the [`eventemitter3`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eventemitter3) library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both answers supplied by cherryblossom and smac89 address the problem. I went with extends EventTarget however minor concerns about the cons associated with it. May ultimately resort to the eventemitter3 but slightly hesitant since the library hasn't been updated in 2 years.